# Regular expression which allow 12 numbers and only one hyphen anywhere

Tags: regex

For example:

```
123-234523234 - true
-123453634342 - true
12-4-45464325 - false
122342322234- - true
```

12 numbers and only 1 hyphen.
Only one time hyphen should come but anywhere in the number field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
/^(?=\d*-\d*$)[\d-]{13}$/
```

Comment: @anubhava: This only seems to match the first example stated above.

Comment: @RoneyMichael I don't think so.

Comment: @RoneyMichael: Just try it :-).

Comment: @user3218114: Just did at http://regex101.com/. Am I doing something wrong? Ref: http://regex101.com/r/qP6eP5/1

Comment: @RoneyMichael provide a valid link. you might forget to add `m` for multi-line match.

Comment: @user3218114: Updated link above.

Comment: @RoneyMichael add global `g` or `m` modifier as per the language choosend to match for next line. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qP6eP5/2)

Comment: @M42: Just noticed you have a minor issue with this regex. See my deleted answer above. Regex should be: `^(?=\d*-\d*$)[\d-]{13}$` with extra `$` in lookahead.